# How do I find what packages I've installed via terminal?

Tags: macports, command-line, package-management

I've been learning the shell for a few weeks and have installed several packages. I know/remember what some of them are, like oh-my-zsh and emacs 24 (which was a nightmare to upgrade to), but not sure sure about what else. I've used different methods like curl, wget and Macports.

My question is, if and when I want to do a clean installation of MacOS, how do I backup or script a fresh installation of these packages? In other words, when I do a new install of MacOS I won't be restoring from Time Machine using Migration Assistant: rather I'll install the system and manually restore files. How do I know the installation paths and dependancies of what I've installed in my previous installation using the command line? Is there a txt file somewhere that the system maintains to keep track of what has been installed?

(MacOS 10.8.2)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since OS X has no package manager, anything you install would have been manual, through MacPorts or through Installer.

If you want a list of the binaries your terminal has access to, you can run the following commands to check the most common spots, and output the result as a text file:

```
touch ~/Binaries.txt
ls /usr/bin > ~/Binaries.txt
ls /usr/sbin >> ~/Binaries.txt
ls /usr/local/bin >> ~/Binaries.txt
ls /usr/local/sbin >> ~/Binaries.txt
ls /opt/local/bin >> ~/Binaries.txt
ls /opt/local/sbin >> ~/Binaries.txt
```

Alternatively, if you just want to get the packages installed by MacPorts, run the following (**this is probably the one you want**):

```
touch ~/MacPorts.txt
port installed > ~/MacPorts.txt
```

And for [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
touch ~/HomeBrew.txt
brew list > ~/HomeBrew.txt
```

And finally, for all packages installed by Installer

```
touch ~/InstalledPackages.txt
pkgutil --packages > ~/InstalledPackages.txt
```

To restore, for example, your MacPorts ports from the list generated above, use the following:

```
 port install $(cat ~/MacPorts.txt)
```

Comment: No problem! Please mark it as accepted if it solves your problem :)

Comment: Isn't it better to run `port list requested` rather than `port installed`, so that MacPorts installs only the dependencies that are in use and in the right order?

Comment: `brew list` includes all the dependency packages too; to list only the top-level packages that you installed explicitly, use `brew leaves`.

Answer (score 0):

List ports that you've installed:

```
port echo requested > ports.txt
```

To later install the latest versions of those ports on a new system

```
sudo port install $(cut -f1 -d\  ports.txt | uniq)
```

See also

```
port help echo
```